# Make instance with newuser by terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I want to make new instance with "user1" rather than ec2-user(AWS) default.i want achieve this by terraform. Like in azure terraform it can be done by "os_profile{}", but how can i do in aws by terraform scripts?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082225/make-instance-with-newuser-by-terraform

Answer (score 2):

AWS AMIs come with a default username - which username it is depends on the specific AMI that is launched. Amazon Linux AMIs use `ec2-user`, CentOS uses `centos`, and there's other combinations too.

If you want to create your own user on instance launch, you can use [EC2 User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for this, which essentially entails passing a custom script that will be run at launch time.

The [`user_data` argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data) is supported by Terraform's `aws_instance` resource. You can specify a script inline, but for most cases you'll probably want to use an external file or template.

For example:

**create-user.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

useradd mytestuser

# Anything else you want to do to set up your user account
```

**main.tf**:

```
resource "aws_instance" "main" {
  ...
  user_data = "${file("create-user.sh")}"
}
```

Alternatively, there's an example on rendering a template [here](http://roshpr.net/blog/2016/10/terraform-using-user-data-in-launch-configuration/), which is useful if you want to pass through custom values rather than just provide a static file.

Or, as an alternative to writing your own shell script, you could try rendering a cloudinit config file using [`template_cloudinit_config`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/cloudinit_config.html). Some resources that might be useful for this include [this blog post](https://ash.berlintaylor.com/writings/2017/08/reusable-terraform-modules-extending-userdata/) and [this part of the cloudinit documentation](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks,this is working..But i want know hoe we can pass the arguments in terraform while executing bash script>beacause i want to pass the RSA key through arguments.e.g.provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "user2.sh '${aws_key_pair.key.public_key}' "
    }

Comment: I covered that in the second last para - see the link there to the example on rendering a template.